# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta código Javascript en librería Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

Tengo el siguiente html con su javascript pero no se visualiza, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")
).Line(LineChart, {scaleFontSize : 13, scaleFontColor : "#ffa45e"});
var LineChart = {
 labels: ["Ruby", "jQuery", "Java", "ASP.Net", "PHP"],
 datasets: [{
 fillColor: "rgba(151,249,190,0.5)",
 strokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
 pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
 pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
 data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
 }, {
 fillColor: "rgba(252,147,65,0.5)",
 strokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
 pointColor: "rgba(173,173,173,1)",
 pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
 data: [28, 68, 40, 19, 96]
 }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis está mal. Chart.js debe recibir los labels y los datasets en la propiedad `data` del objeto de configuración:

```
Chart.Line(ctx, {
  data: {
    labels: [ ... ],
    datasets: [ { ... } ]
  },
  options: { ... }
});
```

Comment: ademas, la variable `LineChart` se establece despues.

Comment: @EmanuelVe lo que ha hecho el OP está mal por donde se mire. Bien puede usar `Chart.Line` o `Chart({ type: 'line', data, options })`.Lo que ha hecho debería lanzar un error de tipo *Line is not a function* aunque no estoy seguro de eso.

Comment: Queremos snippet!

Comment: @amenadiel Vale, en un momentillo que ando un poco liado ;)